# Mulitplication of Cauchy sequences is well defined

Tags: real-analysis, proof-verification, cauchy-sequences

Is the Following Proof Correct? My Proof concerns the implication $x =
 x'\implies xy = x'y$ in the proposition below.

> **Proposition** Let $x = \text{lim}_{n\to\infty}a_n$, $y = \text{lim}_{n\to\infty}b_n$, and $x' = \text{lim}_{n\to\infty}a_n'$ be
>   real numbers. Then $xy$ is also a real number. Furthermore, if $x =
>  x'$, then $xy = x'y$.

---

*Proof.* Assume that $x'=x\in\mathbf{R}$ and $y\in\mathbf{R}$. Let $\epsilon>0$, by hypothesis $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $(a_n')_{n=0}^{\infty}$ are equivalent and $(b_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ is Cauchy-Sequence therefore for some $N\in\mathbf{N}$ we have $\forall n\ge N(|a_n-a_n'|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{M})$ where $M\in\mathbf{Q}^+$ is a bound for $(b_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ whose existence is guarteed by Lemma $\textbf{5.1.15}$. Now given an arbitrary $k\in\{N,N+1,N+2,\dots \}$ we have $|a_n-a'_n|\leq\frac{\epsilon}{M}$ and so 
$$|a_nb_n-a_n'b_n| = |b_n|\cdot|a_n-a_n'|\leq |b_n|\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{M}$$ but $|b_n|\leq M$ which implies $0<|b_n|\cdot\frac{1}{M}\leq 1$ and so $|b_n|\cdot\frac{\epsilon}{M}\leq\epsilon$ we may therefore conclude that $|a_nb_n-a_n'b_n|\leq\epsilon$
indicating that the sequences $(a_nb_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ and $(a_n'b_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ are equivalent we may therefore surmize that $xy=x'y$.

$\blacksquare$

---

**Note:**

- This problem takes place in the context of defining real numbers as limits of Cauchy-Sequences.
- Lemma $\textbf{5.1.15}$ says that given a cauchy sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^{\infty}$ there exists a positive rational $M$ such that $|a_i|\leq M,\forall i\in\mathbf{N}$.

Comment: I know a little bit of analysis but I am not familiar with the Cauchy sequence construction of the real numbers. If you haven't defined the real numbers yet, what does $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_n$ mean if this sequence tends to an irrational number?

Comment: Where you say that this is in the context of defining real numbers as limits of Cauchy sequences, I think you mean defining real numbers as *equivalence classes* of Cauchy sequences? After all, the whole point of the construction is that the Cauchy sequences don't *have* limits before the construction, so it's unclear what defining real numbers as their limits would mean.

Comment: Although the OP should explain the point raised in the comments, one possibility is that this question *might* be written in the context of Terence Tao's "Analysis I", which uses a formal notation $LIM a_n$ to represent the equivalence class of a Cauchy sequence $(a_n)$.

Comment: My Apologies to all the participants here for my tardiness and slopiness. Special thanks to @LeeMosher. Indeed We define the real number $x = \text{LIM}_{n\to\infty}a_n$ to be representative of the equivalence class of all equivalent sequences of rationals. My Apologies for the confusion. Thankyou all for your patience.